# Reading registry in both 64 and 32 bit windows

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, registry

I am writing an application in 64 bit Windows-7. In registry I have a key to be read from the path:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\XXXX

I am first trying to open the key using the following code:

```
RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, Path, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hKey)
```

and after that I am able to read the values. This works fine on 64 bit Windows but does not work on 32 bit Windows. What should be done to read it on 32 bit Windows ?

Comment: The thing is, 32-bit apps actually have access virtualization and should only be written for 32-bit Windows; 64-bit Windows will perform the redirection transparently

Comment: So don't try Wow6432Node, since 32-bit Windows doesn't have that

Comment: If i dont use Wow6432Node, it wont work for 64 bit machine also .

Comment: Well, not exactly a problem you have to solve, your 64-bit program isn't going to run.  Assuming you actually build both flavors, consider omitting "Wow6432Node" and including KEY_WOW64_32KEY so you always get the 32-bit view.

Comment: Is your application 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: you must not have `Wow6432Node` in *Path* you need use `RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"Software\\XXXX", 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS|KEY_WOW64_32KEY, &hKey)`

Comment: This is actually documented believe it or not

Comment: On a side note, you should almost never use `KEY_ALL_ACCESS`. For read-only access specify `KEY_READ`, for read/write `KEY_READ|KEY_WRITE`. If you specify more privileges than needed, you may end up getting nothing or force users to run your program with administrator rights all the time. It's a common approach to security in general, which is called "[principle of least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege)".

Comment: @zett42: along those same lines, you usually don't need to use `KEY_READ` and `KEY_WRITE`, either. Use `KEY_QUERY_VALUE` and `KEY_SET_VALUE` instead. `KEY_READ` is a combination of `STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ`, `KEY_QUERY_VALUE`, `KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS`, and `KEY_NOTIFY`, which is overkill if `KEY_QUERY_VALUE` is all you really need. Same with `KEY_WRITE`, which is a combination of `STANDARD_RIGHTS_WRITE`, `KEY_SET_VALUE`, and `KEY_CREATE_SUB_KEY`, which is overkill if `KEY_SET_VALUE`is all you really need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows 64 bit system divide registry into two part. One for 32 and another for 64 bit system. 
I believe you should update your call to following:

```
RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, Path, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS | KEY_WOW64_32KEY, &hKey)
```

Comment: ... and remove "Wow6432Node\" from the path.

Answer (score 3):

The WOW64 emulator, and thus the `Wow6432Node` key, does not exist on 32-bit versions of Windows, only on 64-bit Windows.  A 32-bit application running on a 64-bit Windows is redirected to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\XXXX` key when it tries to access `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\XXXX`.

The correct solution is to always use the normal path without specifying `Wow6432Node` at all.  On 64-bit Windows, use the `KEY_WOW64_32KEY` flag if you want a 64-bit process to access a 32-bit key, and the `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` flag if you want a 32-bit process to access a 64-bit key.

In your example, try this instead:

```
REGSAM Rights = KEY_QUERY_VALUE;
#ifdef _WIN64
Rights |= KEY_WOW64_32KEY;
#endif

RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, TEXT("Software\\XXXX"), 0, Rights, &hKey);
```

Read the MSDN documentation for more details:

[Registry Redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232.aspx)

[Registry Keys Affected by WOW64](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384253.aspx)

[Accessing an Alternate Registry View](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384129.aspx)

Comment: No need for the `#ifdef`, one can use `KEY_WOW64_32KEY` alway as it will be [ignored on 32-bit Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724878(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Thanks! For my MSI installer that is always running as 32bits process, I had to read the 64bits registry, and with the flag `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` it works.